# Mount multiple buckets from different GCP projects with GCS-Fuse

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I was able to setup GCP SDK with ease and mount a bucket from the SDK default project using GCS-Fuse. However, I can't find any documentation referring to multiple buckets from different projects. My user account has access to multiple GCP projects and some of the projects have buckets that I would like to mount and have simultaneous access to.

From what I've read, you have to switch projects in the SDK in order to mount a bucket from that project which would then disconnect you from the other projects bucket. I'm really hoping that I've misread some part of the documentation and my goal is possible.

Comment: Hey @Jeff any chance you found an answer to this since it was posted?

Comment: @JeffWelling No, unfortunately, I haven't.

Comment: We found this was possible by re-defining the env variable for each mount call, but that's quite ugly, we're still on the lookout for a better solution.

Comment: @JeffWelling Is the solution you found the same as in the exisiting answer? If not, could you please post your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple logged accounts or service account credentials (json files) on the same machine, I think you can use a single service account that has enough permissions(storage roles) across all projects.

This is to mount buckets that come from different projects but with a single account.

With this workaround, you don't need to change the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable for every mount command